# Django Nginx Staticfiles not showing in AWS

Tags: django, nginx, amazon-ec2, django-staticfiles, django-static

I have a Django project that I added to AWS. in the development server the site works perfectly fine however I am not able to get my static files to my aws site

**Below is my project Tree and static files are in the project**

[image]

**Below is my settings.py**

[image]

**Below is my nginx server**

[image]

Below is my `supervisor.conf`

```
[program:Khal]
command = /home/samir/KhalEventsVenv/bin/uwsgi --http :9000 --wsgi-file /home/samir/khal-events/src/Khal/Khal/wsgi.py
directory = /home/samir/khal-events/src/Khal/
user = root
autostart = true
autorestart = true
stdout_logfile = /var/log/Khal.log
stderr_logfile = /var/log/Khal_err.log
```

**Changed the nginx to**

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    location /static/admin {
        alias /home/samir/KhalEventsVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin;

    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /home/samir/khal-events/src/Khal/staticfiles;

    }
```

Still the page is not getting the static in see image below

[image]

I have checked the paths. they are good. However for some reason when I run the site from AWS it is not getting the staticfiles also when I got to the admin page. The static files for admin are not in there too. HOw can I get my static files in AWS

[image]

As suggested by @CoolestNerdIII

[image]

Comment: Have you run the `python manage.py collectstatic` command on your server ? See [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/#deployment) for more details.

Comment: @Anto I just added my `supervisor.conf` file in the question. To run server I do `supervisorctl restart all`

Comment: If you have an ssh access to your server just go there and run `python manage.py collectstatic` in the correct directory and then restart your wsgi server.

Comment: @Anto I did the collectstatic I have updated image of the terminal in question. But still the static file are not showing

Comment: Your static files (where you do collectstatic) is a different location than where nginx is pointing to

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though in your django settings file, you define the static file directory to be `/home/samir/khal-events/src/Khal/staticfiles` (based on your screenshot of your `collectstatic` command and your `settings.py` file).

In your nginx config file, however, you are looking for your static directory inside of `home/samir/khal-events/src/Khal/static`. You need to change this to the correct path, and you should be good to go. (meaning use `/home/samir/khal-events/src/Khal/staticfiles`)

---

Update #1:

You should remove the `/static/admin` from your nginx. Also, you can try duplicating your `/static` group with `/static/`. Make sure you restart your nginx service after you make the changes.

Finally, if neither if these appear to display the page correctly, check the console log in your web browser, as well as the nginx logs, as they typically point to where information is being loaded improperly.

---

Update #2:

```
location /static/ {
    alias /home/samir/khal-events/src/Khal/staticfiles;
}

location /static {
    alias /home/samir/khal-events/src/Khal/staticfiles;
}
```

Comment: changed the static in nginx see image above also ran collectstatic command but still the admin page is weird and even in the normal site there is no static imported

Comment: @SamirTendulkar I updated my answer with something to try.

Comment: I have changed my nginx as per your advise and updated it in th equestion above. Does that look right I am planning on restarting nginx with `sudo systemctl restart nginx`

Comment: tried your code also tried `location /static/ {
    alias /home/samir/khal-events/src/Khal/staticfiles;
}  

location /static {
    alias /home/samir/khal-events/src/Khal/staticfiles/;
}` still the same Also tried extra `/` in the second path

Comment: Did you look at your nginx logs and look for console errors in your browser?

Comment: http://ec2-54-157-27-88.compute-1.amazonaws.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/ that is the aws link. does not show any errors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183373/discussion-between-coolestnerdiii-and-samirtendulkar).

Answer (score 0):

what works for me was just to change the `root` to `alias` I hope this helps